# Eigenvalues of linear operator over complex vector space over the field R

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, determinant

I am tasked with the following. Consider $V= \mathbb{C}^2$ as a vector space over the field $\mathbb{R}$ and define L on V as follows:

$$L\begin{bmatrix}
           a \\
           b
         \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
           Im(b) - iRe(a) \\
           Im(a) - iRe(b)
         \end{bmatrix}$$ with $\begin{bmatrix}
           a \\
           b
         \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{C}^2$

Task **(a)**: Give a possible basis for V. What is the dimension of V?

Task **(b)**: Compute the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of L.

**Q1**: It seems to me that the way L is defined, it is not over the field over $\mathbb{R}$ but $\mathbb{C}$. Am I missing something or is my insight correct?

**Q2**: For task (a) I constructed the basis: $ B = (\begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
           i \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           1
         \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           i
         \end{bmatrix})$,
with dimension 4. However for task(b) representing L in terms of this basis gives the following matrix: A =
$\begin{bmatrix}
           -i & 0 & 0 & 1\\
           0 & 1 & -i & 0
         \end{bmatrix}$. But then, since A is not a square matrix I cannot compute $det(A - \lambda I) =0 $ (to find the eigenvalues of A). How could I solve this? It seems that I'd need a different basis but I am unsure what could it be s.t. it yields a square matrix as well as it is over the field $\mathbb{R}$. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Use $\Bbb C\cong \Bbb R^2$ with basis $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, and then $\Bbb C^2\cong \Bbb R^4$.

Answer (score 1):

As for Q1, $L:V\to V$ is a linear operator, and the scalars are from $\Bbb{R}$.

For Q2, the representing matrix is (where $B=\{v_1,...,v_4\}$ is your basis):

$[T]_B=([T(v_1)]_B\ [T(v_2)]_B\ [T(v_3)]_B\ [T(v_4)]_B)$. Notice that your matrix should have entries from $\Bbb{R}$ because $L$ is a linear transformation over the reals.

So the representation matrix is:

$\begin{bmatrix}
           0& 0 &  0&1 \\
           -1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
           0&1&0&0\\
0&0&-1&0
         \end{bmatrix}$

which is a square matrix for which you can calculate eigenvalues.

Comment: how do you construct this representation matrix? applying L to my basis  B does not yield this. I think one would get -i instead of the -1's if I used a basis D = ((1,0,0,0)^T, (0,i,0,0)^T, ...)

Comment: @cbakos $L(1,0)=(-i,0)\\L(i,0)=(0,1)\\L(0,1)=(0,-i)\\L(0,i)=(1,0)$

Notice that $[T]_B\in M_n(\Bbb{R})$ since $V$ is a vector space with scalars in $\Bbb{R}$, so the matrix's entries cannot be $i$ but only real numbers. That's why you needed $(0,i), (i,0)$ in your basis in the first place.